# Prevent redundant WordPress plugin code - location of shared code files

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, code-reuse, reusability

I am currently writing my first WordPress plugin. Since I am pretty sure this will not be my last one, I try to put as much code as possible into common code files for later reuse in other plugins.

I am using namespaces and OOP programming to allow the code being reused like I do in my C++ projects (as far as PHP allows to do so).

However in WordPress/PHP there is a problem with no obvious solution: Where should I place the shared code files? WordPress kind of merges all the code in a global application. So copying code into each plugin folder could mean potential collisions and/or random use of code files with same content, but different stages of development. Also this would create ugly redundancies.

I did not find a dedicated central storage place.

Placing the shared code in the "plugins" folder is a bad idea since each shared code file would be considered a separate plugin.

I could add all the shared code by means of a special library plugin (as far as I know, this would make the contained code visible to all other plugins), but this seems kind of weird. Also I am not sure if this would be reliable.

What is the best solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding [adamiscoding's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22482127/prevent-redundant-wordpress-plugin-code-location-of-shared-code-files/22483879#22483879): I am trying the proposed hook solution, pushing the framework-plugin to first place in the plugin loading queue. I found some code snippets that should allow to do so, like the following one:

```
add_action('activated_plugin', 'load_this_plugin_first');

function load_this_plugin_first()
{
   $path = plugin_basename(dirname(__FILE__)).'/'.basename(__FILE__);
   if ( $plugins = get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) {
      if ( $key = array_search( $path, $plugins ) ) {
         array_splice( $plugins, $key, 1 );
         array_unshift( $plugins, $path );
         update_option( 'active_plugins', $plugins );
      }
   }
}
```

I disable to dependent plugins entirly if the framework plugin was not installed/activated, so I don't get a bunch errors about missing definitions when loading the plugin administration page in that case. I am using the following check for this:

```
if (!class_exists('Framework\MainClass'))
{
   if (is_admin())
   {
      // What to do here?
   }
}
else
{
   // Normal plugin code
}
```

This seems to work fine.

Currently I am a bit unsure what I should do in case of missing framework. I could automatically deactivate it. Or I could show a persistent admin message... but that isn't that easy, because I get a warning about some characters of "unexpected output" when activating the depended plugin due to the message code line:

```
echo "<div class='updated'><p>Plugin will not work without framework!</p></div>";
```

This is why I try to check if the plugin code is executed during activation, so I can suppress the message in that case:

```
if (!function_exists('is_plugin_active'))
{
   echo "<div class='updated'><p>Plugin will not work without Framework!</p></div>";
}
```

This seems to work too but I wonder if there is a better way to check if a plugin is executed during activation than `function_exists('is_plugin_active')`?

Answer (score 2):

WordPress kind of sucks with reusability in plugins.
As far as I know, there isn't any integrated way to reuse code in WordPress plugins.

You can try out *[Plugin Dependencies](https://github.com/x-team/wp-plugin-dependencies)* plugin to manage dependencies between your plugins. So you can store your generic code under one plugin that will be required by others.

Other approach would be using WordPress hooks/actions system. So you will have to defer your plugin init until the library plugin hook executes.

There are activation/deactivation hooks, so you can do some stuff when the framework is missing.

Take a look a these pages:

- *[Displaying a Plugin Activation Message in WordPress](http://tommcfarlin.com/plugin-activation-message/)*
- *[Function Reference/register activation hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook)*

Comment: Please see my next answer... maybe you have a hint for the question at its bottom too?

Comment: I edited my anwser a bit. Warning is being shown because you should use activation hooks for displaying notices. Activation code should not echo anything itself.